# What should I do to receive turn based match update properly if I use tbmp skeleton but tbmp skeleton is not the main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am attempting to use tbmp skeleton but I do not use it as the main activity.  Everything seems to work except when during testing I try to accept an invitation and get to the next turn screen to perform Turn 1(the second turn). In onActivityResult (in the secondary Activity I start with an Intent) the line:

```
TurnBasedMatch match = data.getParcelableExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);
```

triggers a BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling TurnBasedMatchEntity

The previously asked question on the site about "BadParcelablException on passing TurnBasedMatch in intent" did not provide any useful leads.  I have tried over 2 dozen variations in the code published as alphas and tested.  I have come to the conclusion that the problem is that I do not have tbmp skeleton set up as the main activity.  Is there some way around this problem that does not require me to try to combine my normal main Activity with SkeletonActivity in tbmp?  Otherwise, tbmp as a secondary activity seems to work just fine. It signs in automatically to google+, I can "start match", "check games", "sign out", and start an auto game.  A game created by "start match" lets the starter add to the present string and clicking Done results in a game that can be seen in "check games". Selection of an opponent (my other gmail test account) works.  The other test gmail account can see the game in check games and can accept an invitation.  If the other gmail game process is active and signed in then when the 1st game process sends the invitation I see the toast on the 2nd game process that gives notice that an invitation is received.  However, there is no way to get to Turn 1 assuming getSelectOpponentsIntent is used in onStartMatchClicked.  Replacing getSelectOpponentsIntent with createMatch seems to lead to what is essentially auto match.

If I used auto match to start a game in the 1st test account, and use auto match subsequently in the 2nd test account then in the 2nd account I DO get to Turn 1 but then the same problem reappears because the 1st account can never actually see or make the Turn 2 move.

There are 4 other questions on this site which hit around this problem.
"How to detect Intent from Google Play Services Notification", "How to determine the match selected from a Google Play turn based notification", "TBMP Skeleton:Why are both onTurnBasedMatchReceived and onInvitationReceived not called on physical device", and (peripherally) "TBMP Skeleton-How do I override notification events".  Sync is on for my accounts and notifications is on for Google Play Games.  Adding another extra to the intent and searching for that does not seem to work.  Turning on and off registerMatchUpdateListener and registerInvitationListener does not produce beneficial results.  I think it would be helpful to know what are the needed changes to tbmp skeleton when you shift it to not being the main activity.  To my eyes, this is a common problem with Java code, you often cannot move a code block from one place to another because it will break if you do.

My alternate course of actions are 1)set up tbmp skeleton in an alpha-only google play account and see if problem replicates when SkeletonActivity is the main activity, 2)graft SkeletonActivity onto my normal main activity, 3)drop tbmp skeleton and try to use another example from github or programcreek

Comment: Have tried moving the code from SkeletonActivity to my main activity.   The resulting app appears to produce the same results from before the shift to my old main activity, i.e. all the same behavior and BadParcelableException error results are still occurring. I assume I was wrong about the problem being that I put tbmp skeleton into a non-main activity.  I tried publishing my game services definition for this app. Before this publish I had depended on alpha testing. No real change in the results due the publish that I can see (there was a change in the game state string initially displayd).

Comment: I have since decided to use the real-time example ButtonClicker instead of the turn-based example.  I have found it possible to complete my project that way.  I am not submitting that as an answer to the original question because it isn't.  It is a feasible workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting invitations/match updates via notifications and just not getting your listener called make sure you remembered to register the listeners!!! I spent way too long on this, simply forgot to register the listener(was positive I had too lol).

```
Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **ACCEPT INVITATION** code from android github sample given below:

```
TurnBasedMatch match = data.getParcelableExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);
```

Instead, use the below method to get the match value:

```
public Task<TurnBasedMatch> acceptInvitation (String invitationId)
```

& use event listener to get the match & further proceed to take turn.

If you fail to use the above method, debugging the app works fine while the release version crashes & return the same exception after publishing in play store.

It's not mandatory to register listeners which is depreciated methods & instead register callbacks to get invitation Id.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your proguard configuration:

```
 -keep class  com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatchEntity
```

Consider also adding this one for the invitations:

```
 -keep class com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.InvitationEntity
```